# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I am getting this **YSOD** when I run my MVC app, it was all working fine until I took a latest **Visual Studio 2017 update**.

[image]

What could possibly be causing this issue?

I have also tried adding **System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives**, nope that doesn't work.

I am using **Newtonsoft.Json** version 11.0.0.0

In my Solution explorer the System.Runtime.Primitives shows broken

[image]

**Target Framework 4.7.1**

Comment: Did you try Ticking the `Remove additional files at destination` in `File Publish Option` ; Then clean and rebuild and finally publish it again and check. Hope it works!

Comment: Ok, will try this.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: I get to see this is accepted bug in .NET framework 4.7.0 and they say they will fix it in 4.7.1 https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open PM Console in Visual Studio and run this command:

> Install-Package System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives

Answer (score 1):

I got a fix for this issue from https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/567

I had to remove the entry for 
**System.Runtime.Serialization** and **System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives** from packages.config file, that made it work fine, not sure how did that fix it.